# Distinct values in dropdownlist and Filter on default value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, filter

I have this ViewData and DropDownList that need to have distinct values. Let me get you in context, on my view when I create a "Project" it can set it "style value" to something (it's a string field) for example "Pop". On my index page inside my dropdown filter, i'll have "Pop" in it. If I create a second project that has "Pop" in the style value, the dropdown will display it two times. I don't want that.

Second thing I'm trying to do is to set a default value in my dropdown filter so that when I select that value, it will remove all filters and display the full list of all projects added.

Just say so if I didn't make myself clear.

Here is how it is in my code.

My controller :

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var projects = from s in db.Project select s;
        var projectList = db.Project.ToList();

        if (Request.Form["FilterStyle"] != null && Request.Form["FilterStyle"] != "")
        {
            int i = int.Parse(Request.Form["FilterStyle"]);
            projects = from s in db.Project
                       where s.ID == i
                       select s;
        }

        if (Request.Form["FilterStyle"] == null)
        {
            projects = from s in db.Project select s;
        }

        ViewData["Styles"] = new SelectList(projectList, "ID", "Style");

        return View(projects);
    }
```

My view :

```cs
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr align="left">

        ....

            <th>
                Style :
                <br /><br />
                @Html.DropDownList("FilterStyle", (SelectList)ViewData["Style"], " ", new { onchange = "this.form.submit()" })
            </th>

        ....

        </tr>    
    </thead>

    <tbody>

    ....

    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure in your query before you pass it to the view you will only get distict values.

```
projects = (from s in db.Project
                       where s.ID == i
                       select s).Distinct().ToList();



  var projectList = db.Project.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Just tried this and it doesn't work :/ Also, you can't go for projects = (...).Distinct().ToList(); in this situation :( What's bothering me here is that we are trying to distinct the style value, not all projects. So I think db.Project.Distinct().ToList() is not making sense. Am I wrong?

Comment: you can use more linq https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/ which has an extension diticntBy to distinct based on specific value